# How to add column data as rows in an efficient manner?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe, df, that looks something like this

```
   col1  col2

A   2   2   
B   4   1   
C   0   0   
D   1   1   
E   2   2
```

and would like to add two columns, so that for each row i, the new column col3 contains the value of df.loc[i-1,col1] and col4 contains the value of df.loc[i-2,col1].

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4

A   2   2   Nan Nan 
B   4   1   2   Nan
C   0   0   4   2
D   1   1   0   4
E   2   2   1   0
```

As of now, I loop through the dataframe and "manually" add each value. Is there a smarter way to solve this problem than my approach?

My brute-force solution (neglecting first 2 rows):

```
for i in range(2,df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(2):
        df.iloc[i,j+2] = df.iloc[i-1-j, j]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with a `map` and `pd.concat`

```
df.join(
    pd.concat(
        dict(enumerate(map(df.col1.shift, range(1, 3)), 3)), axis=1
    ).add_prefix('col')
)

   col1  col2  col3  col4
A     2     2   NaN   NaN
B     4     1   2.0   NaN
C     0     0   4.0   2.0
D     1     1   0.0   4.0
E     2     2   1.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `shift`

```
for x in range(2): 
    df['col'+str(x+3)]=df.col1.shift(x+1)
df
Out[152]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
A     2     2   NaN   NaN
B     4     1   2.0   NaN
C     0     0   4.0   2.0
D     1     1   0.0   4.0
E     2     2   1.0   0.0
```